# Trackpad and Keyboard malfunctioning

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

I have a MacBook Pro Early 2011 (now vintage) running macOS Sierra without any problem whatsoever. However, my trackpad sometimes (very frequently) starts to malfunction or stops to function at all.
I am using an external mice without problems. On the keyboard, sometimes [it] starts malfunctioning when I type really fast which I believe it's correlated with the Trackpad issue.

Things I already did:
- Fresh install
- New Battery
- Reset NPRAM
- Ran Apple Hardware Test no issues shown.

Theories:
- Some electrical charge probably messed up my trackpad and Apple Hardware Test is not showing it (however sometimes trackpad works perfectly fine).

- My MacBook has a small dent so the bottom case is not completely closed, could it be that is getting dust, debris or even some weird electrical issue?
- On the inside, the Trackpad and Keyboard Cable usually contains this bracket (see pic below) however my my MacBook doesn't have it. Could that be an issue?

Next Steps:
I'm looking for some theories as well in here before I actually buy extra pieces as I'm on a budget. Replacing the bottom case with keyboard and trackpad seems to be the safest choice but the most expensive and the bracket seems like the cheapest and quicker way.
Please any help is appreciated!

[image: bracket]

Comment: That bracket is used to **secure** the keyboard assembly cable - why is is it missing?  This may very well be the issue of your ***intermittent*** keyboard/trackpad problems.

Comment: Is missing because an iShop (mexican authorized distributor) drop it without me realizing this until now. Too late to complaint. Any suggestions to test if this is actually the issue before buying the piece? Black tape? Or some quick test?

Comment: There's no "test" for a poor physical connection.  I would try securing it with some tape like you suggested (but use [Kapton tape](http://amzn.to/2r6jswH), not black electrical) and if the problem goes away, that's the issue.  I would also see if you can find the part online and replace it.

Comment: @Allan you were right. I just installed the part I bought and it works (so far) ... hopefully that'll be it. If you could answer this or let me answer it... is up to you. MANY THANKS!

Comment: If it works, go ahead and write it up,  I'll be sure to upvote so you can get some more reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

After much research it turns out it was not the bracket itself. Although I have to tell that the keyboard behaved better after installing the bracket.
I had to replace my trackpad entirely after all so probably something messed up my trackpad or just regular lifecycle (my MBP is 6 years old now...)